# NetSuite Saved search - available inventory comparison between 2 locations

Tags: switch-statement, netsuite, saved-searches

I am trying to build a saved search that can perform available inventory comparison between two locations.  It will display  inventory items that have low inventory less than or equal to 2 at one location, and if the same items have inventory available at another location equal to or greater than 2, so we then use that information to perform inventory transfers. Ideally, I want to then use the saved search and try to build a scheduled workflow to then create auto inventory transfer records.
I currently have a saved search which lists columns of available inventory by each location. We then have to export the saved search into excel and then filter down the list of items based on above comparisons, and then create inventory transfers via csv imports. Again, at this point I am trying to build a saved search which will eliminate the use of excel.

Comment: So far I've tried this, but I'm getting syntax error: CASE WHEN {inventorylocation.id} = '1' AND {locationquantityavailable} >= 2 THEN 1 WHEN {inventorylocation} '6' AND {locationquantityavailable} <= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Comment: You are missing a comparison operator in the second WHEN clause ({inventorylocation} '6').

Comment: Will it be like this? CASE WHEN {inventorylocation.id} = '1' AND {locationquantityavailable} >= 2 THEN (CASE WHEN {inventorylocation.id} = '6' AND {locationquantityavailable} <= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE 0 END

Answer (score 0):

CASE WHEN {inventorylocation.id} = '1' AND {locationquantityavailable} >= 2 THEN (CASE WHEN {inventorylocation.id} = '6' AND {locationquantityavailable} <= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE 0 END
Yes , this worked for me